# Understand the lyrics of Coco's “Ne m'oublie pas”

Tags: grammaire, verbes-pronominaux, élision

I found the lyrics of the song here: [Les paroles de la chanson: Ne m’oublie pas, du film Coco](http://lemondededisney.com/les-paroles-de-la-chanson-ne-moublie-pas-du-film-coco/).

And although it's relatively simple, I am struggling a bit to understand the grammar point of the 2 sentences:

- *Je vais devoir m’en aller.*
- *Pour que tu n’aies plus peur.*

I am not sure which part of the full sentence “en” is supposed to replace and is “m'” the short form of “me”? If yes then what does “me aller” mean?

Why is *avoir* conjugated as “aie” in the second sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the idiom in French is: **s'en aller and it means: to go away or to leave.**

You need to memorize that one.

And this is how it works in French: the en stands for a place but is used as an idiom even when the actual place where the people are does not appear in the sentence:

*Nous devons nous en aller tout de suite*=We should leave [this  place] right away.

- **Tu t'en vas là?** =Are you leaving now? [là can mean now when a speaker is referring to what the other party to the conversation is doing]

Bonus answer: another idiom that is extremely useful along these lines is: 
**en vouloir à quelqu'un**=to resent someone or to hold something against someone for doing something or be mad or annoyed at them.

It's a good idea to memorize these and practice them as they are tricky at first for FLL.

Answer (score 3):

Answering to your second question: The subjunctive mood is mandatory after several conjunctions like here ***pour que***, thus:

> *...pour que tu n'aies plus peur.*

and never:

> *...pour que tu <s>n'as</s> plus peur.*

or

> *...pour que tu <s>n'auras</s> plus peur.*

[Here is a list of cases](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif#Emplois_du_subjonctif) showing where the subjunctive is required.